# i want to show pdf file in Android Activity with WebView but after run project nothing show up

Tags: android, pdf, url, android-webview

I have project that show pdf in activity with webView from url but when project output comes that's empty display, nothing else, what I have to change this project that show pdf.

menifeat.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

mainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final WebView webView;

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdfhttps://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf");
}
```

}

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the user @CommonsWare say, you can't open a PDF in the webview.
The best solution would be download it and send it across an intent to a PDF dedicated reader app the user should have, or implement a special class to open it inside your own app.

Comment: `WebView` has no built-in ability to render a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the process you want with **PDFRenderer**.

[Dıc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html)

Comment: is this true? (it doesn't show anything, just blank output)                https://medium.com/@chahat.jain0/rendering-a-pdf-document-in-android-activity-fragment-using-pdfrenderer-442462cb8f9a